# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined - phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, push-notification

I am creating a JQuery mobile Application wrapped by Cordova to get native mobile build.

I need to implement push notification and my Application supports Android and IOS. SO I started with Android. I created a project in Google developer console - https://console.developers.google.com/

Then I installed a  [push notification plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) using CLI command

```
cordova plugin add /path/to/plugin/directory
```

When I add the files in my index.html, the order is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="push.js"></script>
```

When I run the Application it says, **Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined**

I tried swapping the file declaration in index.html. Also removing and installing the plugin again but no luck.

Can you help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you please post the complete error stack?

Comment: The error stack given is Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined push.js line:206